# Euro/Foreign Exchange Volumes

Tags: fx

I'm trying to put together a financial analysis notebook as part of a data science program. One thing I am trying to find is the frequency of currencies that are traded with the Euro. I have looked at the Triennial Central Bank Survey for 2019 from BIS, but that's global volumes. I am looking for something similar but targeted to just the Euro.

Thank you.

Comment: This BIS report Table 3 and Table 4 (US against other currencies (incl EUR) , EUR against other currencies) can be used, I believe, to get the data you want https://www.bis.org/statistics/rpfx19_fx_annex.pdf

Comment: Table 4 is good, I was kinda hoping for more of the Other column. I am looking forward to the 2022 TCB. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See also https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/markets/london-foreign-exchange-joint-standing-committee/results-of-the-semi-annual-fx-turnover-survey-october-2020

This is not "targeted to just the Euro" but does cover the euro.

Comment: Thank you. I'd upvote but don't have enough points on the site. :)